# jquery picture change and switch position

Tags: jquery, web, switch-statement

Hi i'm doing a sample site that has a 4 pictures, there is a default picture where it is the largest picture, when i click the 2nd picture the 2nd picture will be the one in that position and the 1st picture will be on the 2nd pictures position. same goes in the 3rd picture and the 4th picture. how can i do it in jquery thanks in advance for those who want to help...

Comment: HAve you tried anything yet ?

Comment: im searching the net for almost 2hrs now, nothing so far...

Comment: You need to explain it properly so that I can take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your complete solution! ;)

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img.prodSmallPic').click(function() {
        var tmpObjSrcBig = $('img.prodBigPic').attr('rel');
        var tmpObjSrcSmall = $(this).attr('rel');

        $('a[id="' + $(this).attr('rel') + '"]').attr('id', tmpObjSrcBig);

        $('img.prodBigPic').fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('img.prodBigPic').attr('src', 'big_' + $(this).attr('rel'));
            if (this.complete) $(this).fadeIn(200);
        });
        $(this).fadeOut(200, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', 'tn_' + tmpObjSrcBig);
            if (this.complete) $(this).fadeIn(200);
        });

        $('img.prodBigPic').attr('rel', tmpObjSrcSmall);
        $(this).attr('rel', tmpObjSrcBig);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<img src="big_11886333_1.jpg" border="0" class="prodBigPic" rel="11886333_1.jpg" />

<img src="tn_11886333_2.jpg" class="prodSmallPic" border="0" rel="11886333_2.jpg" />
<img src="tn_11886333_3.jpg" class="prodSmallPic" border="0" rel="11886333_3.jpg" />
```

Online demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/8xmLM

Hope this help!

Comment: im having a problem in the picture switching, your provided site produce a correct process... but when i try it, the big picture will disappear when i click the small pic... i try to copy and paste all the codes and it still produce the same output...

Comment: i cant understand exactly whats your problem.  can you explain it?

Comment: nah its solved the problem is my path to the picture :D thnx again